# Need some domain knowledge

Tags: sentiment-analysis

I am looking for some BD (Business Development) help. 
I am building a product that does sentiment analysis. 
I want to know which domains in the internet space (for which there are online/offline "reviews" from users available) I can cater my product to for their review analysis needs.

Answer (score 1):

In retail domain, you can find reviews of products from e-commerce sites. Sentiment analysis on the reviews of a product can be leveraged by the manufacturer for that product lifecycle management and/or in ideation of production of similar kind of a new product in the market.

Comment: Can you compare which one is more generic, easy and more trending on the internet among hospitality (hotel/restaurant based reviews like Zomato), retail (like Amazon)? I am also thinking about the clarity and exclusivity of aspects I can classify the reviews into.